# Unexpected behaviour with PHP trim() native function

Tags: php, php-8.1

## Is this for real?

Native PHP trim function uses the `$char_double` by default. I expected the `$trimmed_single_double` to be as `$trimmed_matching_double`.
This code was tested on https://onlinephp.io/c/9799e2b3-6598-447b-9ca1-31218983d9e1 using (PHP 8.1.12). Feel free go check it out.

I want to believe I'm doing something wrong. I'm nervous.

##### Code (PHP 8.1.12)

```
<?php

$text_double = "\n text \n";
$text_single = '\n text \n';

$char_double = " \t\n\r\0\x0B";
$char_single = ' \t\n\r\0\x0B';

$trimmed_matching_double = trim($text_double, $char_double);
$trimmed_matching_single = trim($text_single, $char_single);
$trimmed_single_double = trim($text_single, $char_double);

var_dump([
    'trimmed_matching_double' => $trimmed_matching_double, 
    'trimmed_matching_single' => $trimmed_matching_single,
    'trimmed_single_double' => $trimmed_single_double,
]);
```

##### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["trimmed_matching_double"]=>
  string(4) "text"
  ["trimmed_matching_single"]=>
  string(1) "e"
  ["trimmed_single_double"]=>
  string(10) "\n text \n"
}
```

Please shed some light on this. Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you told us what you think is wrong

Comment: *Is this for real?* errrmmm  - possibly!

Comment: In this `$char_single = ' \t\n\r\0\x0B';` as its wrapped in single quotes you are storing  `\t\n\r\0\x0B` and not tabs amd newlines etc because in a single quoted string they are just a list of characters

Comment: To visualize the explanations: If you would `var_dump()` your variables before doing anything with it, you would get `string(8) "
 text 
"` and `string(10) "\n text \n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [single quotes in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning

So:
When you trim single with single, it will remove all characters (`'\'`, `'n'`, `' '`, `'t'`, etc.)

When you try to remove double with single, it find nothing, because `'\n'` is considered a single character. He cannot fina a single `'\'` or a single `'n'`.